Get size of autowrapped label text in Godot
var info = Label.new()

# minimum sizes of the rect it will be inside
info.custom_minimum_size.x = info_wide
info.custom_minimum_size.y = anim_height

# long text in one line with autowrap
info.text = descs[i - 1] 
info.autowrap_mode = TextServer.AUTOWRAP_WORD_SMART

Before i had case where there was no need in autowrap and just get_combined_minimum_size() was enought, but here textes are need to be long, therefore need to know height of autowrapped text.
var info_rect = ColorRect.new()
info_rect.custom_minimum_size.x = info_wide - 8 # -8 for scroll bar

info_rect.custom_minimum_size.y = info.get_combined_minimum_size().y # this wont work
info_rect.color = Color(0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.35)
info_rect.add_child(info)


var infoCont = ScrollContainer.new()
infoCont.horizontal_scroll_mode = ScrollContainer.SCROLL_MODE_DISABLED
infoCont.vertical_scroll_mode = ScrollContainer.SCROLL_MODE_SHOW_ALWAYS
infoCont.custom_minimum_size.x = info_wide
infoCont.custom_minimum_size.y = anim_height
infoCont.add_child(info_rect)

The result should be scroll container with color rect in with label in and ability to scroll text inside the box of size of scroll container, but sizes of color rect are the ones of label.
I didn't found a way to find a height of autowrapped label text to cahange info_rect.custom_minimum_size.y because info.get_line_count() returns 1 and  autowrap does not affect info.custom_minimum_size.y or info.get_combined_minimum_size().y
info.get_visible_line_count() * info.get_line_height() does not work
